# How to get full javac compiler error with maven?

Tags: maven, build, compiler-errors, javac

I'm currently learning how to use Maven to build projects that I write in Java. Before, I've  only used `javac` to compile my projects and I've gotten used to the error messages produced by it. I tried to compile the following erroneous, test program using `mvn compile` and then `javac` manually:

```
public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.print(a);
    }
}
```

`javac` produces:

```
App.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.print(a);
                     ^
  symbol:   variable a
  location: class App
1 error
```

but `mvn compile` produces this (among a bunch of other stacktraces and output):

```
...     
[ERROR] /home/htor/maven-test/cflat/src/main/java/no/uio/ifi/cflat/App.java:[5,25] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
...
```

The latter is not as useful as the first error message and it doesn't contain the full error message from `javac`. I've tried using `-e` and `-X` but the error is reported identically, just with more noice around.

How can I get the **full** Javac error message in the error messages from Maven?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching a bit more it seems this behaviour was caused by a bug in the Maven compiler plugin. The solution to this question solved my problem: [maven "cannot find symbol" message unhelpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164386/maven-cannot-find-symbol-message-unhelpful). Just add this to your `pom.xml` file to use the newest `compiler` plugin:

```
<project>
    ...
    <build>
        ....
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: You rock.  The current version of swagger codegen (2.1.4) creates a pom.xml with the old, bad value.  This made errors sensible again.