# Cannot find symbol PathParam in Jersey

Tags: java, maven, jersey, jax-rs

Here's my code

```
@Path("/users/{id}")
public class MyResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getId(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        return "Getting Messages for User : " + id;
    }
}
```

All i get is

```
..MyResource.java:[17,29] error: cannot find symbol
```

So far i have checked both this
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVERKB/Maven+2+plugin+fails+with+cannot+find+symbol+exception+when+defining+two+locations+for+source+files

& this

[maven "cannot find symbol" message unhelpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164386/maven-cannot-find-symbol-message-unhelpful)

but without any success.

**EDIT:** pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.placeholder</groupId>
    <artifactId>edelivery-sp</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>edelivery-sp</name>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support:
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.placeholder.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.16</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Comment: You really need to show your palm if this is a build problem.

Comment: You are missing the jaxrs api classes but this is probably due to missing the jersey-core library. Depends on which version of jersey you are using 1.x or 2.x

Comment: @ChrisHinshaw You mean my pom file? http://pastebin.com/VCrXwjRr

Comment: Dumb question, but did you import it? `import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;`

Comment: @peeskillet YES, that was it. I had overlooked it in every possible tutorial i checked. Want to repost it to mark it as answered?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was looking at your pom.xml in your link, and it looks like you are using a Maven archetype that I am familiar with. The code you've posted is the only class provided by the archetype. Only difference is, your addition of the `@PathParam` (and the change of path). In which case, you still need to import the annotation :-)

```
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
```

Comment: I ran into something very much like this.  The problem was actually that Eclipse had auto-imported a different PathParam for me:  javax.websocket.server.PathParam.  All my code compiled under Eclipse, but choked with Maven.  Of course, I wanted javax.ws.rs.PathParam.