# JCenter maven dependency results in package not found

Tags: java, maven, jcenter

I am trying to use some dependency coming from JCenter, rather than the standard maven repositories, but when using

```
mvn clean install
```

this results in the following error in my maven output (Compilation error)

```
package com.bol.api.openapi_4_0 does not exist
cannot find symbol
symbol:   class SearchResults
location: class be.goedkoperzoeken.results.BolSearchResults
```

Etc.

This is my pom.xml for my project

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>bla.foo.blaat</groupId>
<artifactId>bolapi</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>blaat</name>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.bol.openapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>openapi-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>bintray-pvdissel-bol-com-releases</id>
        <name>bintray</name>
        <url>http://dl.bintray.com/pvdissel/bol-com-releases</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>bintray-pvdissel-bol-com-releases</id>
        <name>bintray-plugins</name>
        <url>http://dl.bintray.com/pvdissel/bol-com-releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

What am I missing here? It seems to me like my pom.xml has all the information required and Eclipse does not seem to complain.

Comment: Could be a bug, depending on the version of your JDK. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164386/maven-cannot-find-symbol-message-unhelpful).

Comment: I'm currently using JDK 1.8.0.51

Comment: I am having the same issue with a 1.7JDK.

Comment: Please check your settings.xml for presence of mirror-any tag.

Comment: I'll have a look at it this evening, JBaruch. It's also only a problem when I do a mvn clean install, when I just run it as an application through a main method (using Spring Tool Suite 3.7.0) it runs perfectly.