# How to make maven-compiler-plugin not hide error source locations

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-compiler-plugin

Maybe there is a `maven-compiler-plugin` option for this, but I haven't found it.

When `javac` is run directly and prints an error, after the first line of the message, *it shows the affected line of source* with a caret on the next line pointing to the error position. It looks like this:

```
com/invariantproperties/udt/sql/RationalUDT.java:324: error: cannot find symbol
    public static boolean lessThan(RRationalUDT p, double q) {
                                   ^
  symbol:   class RRationalUDT
  location: class RationalUDT
```

Notice the lines that point directly at where I misspelled the type name. The `maven-compiler-plugin` shows it like this:

```
[ERROR] /var/tmp/pljava-udt-type-extension/java/src/main/java/com/invariantproperties/udt/sql/RationalUDT.java:[324,36] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class RRationalUDT
  location: class com.invariantproperties.udt.sql.RationalUDT
```

Notice it *got rid of the line(s) actually pointing to the error*. (This is using Oracle JDK 7.)

Ok, so at first I thought [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14164386/4062350) was going to have the answer, because it was also about `maven-compiler-plugin` not showing the whole error message, and it said the fix was to update to `maven-compiler-plugin` version 3.1.

But for this issue I have tried 2.4, 3.1, and 3.5 without any improvement. The lines displaying the error are always missing.

This applies to any `javac` error. In the example I misspelled a symbol just to get the same error that the older question was talking about. But I can fix that one and make another one (this one comes from a `javac` annotation processor):

```
com/invariantproperties/udt/sql/RationalUDT.java:324: error: No known mapping to an SQL type
    public static boolean lessThan(RationalUDT p, double q) {
                                               ^
```

and here again what the `maven-compiler-plugin` shows is only:

```
[ERROR] /var/tmp/pljava-udt-type-extension/java/src/main/java/com/invariantproperties/udt/sql/RationalUDT.java:[324,47] error: No known mapping to an SQL type
```

I mean, at least it shows the line and column in brackets, so it's not totally impossible to find the error, but the normal display from `javac` is even more helpful. Is there any way to have the `maven-compiler-plugin` not hide it?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible and a feature request is already pending on the official [Maven Compiler JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER)

> [**MCOMPILER-229**](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-229): Compilation error should be reported as by javac tool

The ticket is in status **OPEN** at the time of writing and created since 25/Jul/**14**.

You can either propose a patch or - at least - vote for the ticket (I just did it).

Comment: Ah nice, I searched for one but couldn't find it.