# How do I get the Maven compiler plugin to print out what symbol caused a "Cannot find symbol" compilation failure?

Tags: java, maven, compiler-errors, maven-compiler-plugin

I’m using Maven 3.3 with the following compiler configuration …

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                <fork>true</fork>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-testCompile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I run “mvn clean install,” I get the following compiler error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project core: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /Users/davea/Documents/my_workspace/myproject/src/test/java/org/mainco/subco/mainpkg/subunit/MyTest.java:[248,15] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

My question is, is there a way I con configure things so that the system tellms me what symbol it cannot find?  Sometimes it does this but sometimes not.  Below is the line but my question deals more with printing out more specific error messages, as opposed to compiling the below line.

```
        Assert.asertNotNull("A pre-condition of this test is that an object exist witih id \"" + id + "\".", obj);
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35256796/how-to-make-maven-compiler-plugin-not-hide-error-source-locations

Comment: There is a pending request since 2014! check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/36107638/5606016