# No compile errors but still cannot find symbol on Maven

Tags: java, maven

I am having a weird issue. I added an interface in a different module, and the IDE compiles fine and everything works fine when I run it on my IDE, but when I do `mvn clean install` I get an error saying `cannot find symbol MyInterface`. Here is the log of the `mvn clean install`:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/path/to/MyClass.java:[5,37] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MyInterface
  location: package path.to.where.interface.lives
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
```

And the line in `MyClass.java` where it's complaining about is:

`import path.to.where.interface.lives.MyInterface;`

And my interface looks like this:

```
package path.to.where.interface.lives;

public interface MyInterface {
    public void method();
}
```

I even added the dependency to the `path.to.where.interface.lives` package, in the pom file of where `MyClass.java` lives, but I am still seeing the issue.

Comment: On a side note `myInterface` should be named as `MyInterface` and `myClass` should be named as `MyClass`.

Comment: Post the code of `myClass.java`.

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164386/maven-cannot-find-symbol-message-unhelpful

Comment: I doubt `interface` is a valid package component, for it's a keyword. If the package name is really `path.to.where.interface.lives`, then this package name is invalid, and should be renamed to something like `path.to.where.myinterface.lives`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by running `mvn clean install` on the entire project first, as I was originally running `mvn clean install` only on a specific module.